# Reversing Vertex Order in Shader

Tags: three.js, vertex-shader

I want to reverse the order that vertices are fed to a vertex shader.  Any suggestions?  I'm using ThreeJS, but the shader is custom.

**Some background information:**
To solve the problem in the past, when I wasn't using a custom shader, I would just create the object geometry like this:

```
new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 16, 16, -32 )
```

instead of:

```
new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 16, 16, 32 )
```

and it would achieve what I need.  The problem is that the geometry I'm using now is created in Blender and imported into the scene.

Comment: You can ask this question on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/), providing more code and details.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to reverse the vertex order?

Perhaps you can just change the sidedness of your material to .side=THREE.BackSide or .side = THREE.DoubleSide if you are trying to solve backface culling problems?

Comment: In the vertex shader I'm moving the vertices in a way that the object swirls/spirals, but it's spiraling downward and I need it to spiral upward.  You would probably think I could just reverse some of the math in the shader, but it's not working that way.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like it would be easiest solved by tweaking your shader.

Comment: If you want to chat about it, or get general THREE.js help, you can join this slack channel and hit me up.. I'm Thrax. https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Just post in #general